# Powershell - renaming files

Tags: powershell, file-rename

I'm new to Powershell and in need of some help.  I have some ideas but I am not sure what direction to go.  This is what I want to do:

1. Search a folder
2. Rename all files found based on the date/string in the file name: (example below)
   Note: these file date/string change with dates

**Old Name:**

testfile_2021-09-20_help

testfile_2021-09-22_help

testfile_2021-09-23_help

testfile_2021-09-24_help

**New Name:**

092021 changefile

092022 changefile

092023 changefile

092024 changefile

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Well what have you tried? we'd like to see your attempt at this

Comment: Looks like a job for regex.

Comment: Seems weird you only want to use the first two digits from the Year part.. What is the use then?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that may help.

```
# echo hi | set-content testfile_2021-09-20_help, testfile_2021-09-22_help,
#   testfile_2021-09-23_help, testfile_2021-09-24_help

dir | rename-item -newname { $_ -match '(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})' > $null;
  $matches.2 + $matches.1 + $matches.3 + " changefile" } -whatif

What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target 
        "Item: C:\Users\admin\foo\testfile_2021-09-20_help 
  Destination: C:\Users\admin\foo\09202120 changefile".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target 
        "Item: C:\Users\admin\foo\testfile_2021-09-22_help 
  Destination: C:\Users\admin\foo\09202122 changefile".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target 
        "Item: C:\Users\admin\foo\testfile_2021-09-23_help 
  Destination: C:\Users\admin\foo\09202123 changefile".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target 
        "Item: C:\Users\admin\foo\testfile_2021-09-24_help 
  Destination: C:\Users\admin\foo\09202124 changefile".
```